# Error compile in "Use Facebook Login" SDK

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I have followed the Facebook "use Facebook Login" [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/)

However, when I load the app and click on "Login" I get the "com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot use SessionLoginBehavior SSO_WITH_FALLBACK when com.facebook.LoginActivity is not declared as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml" error.

I definitely have added the activity in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.zwopper.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.zwopper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
</application>
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

(I have also added the *app_id* string to res/values/strings.xml, the INTERNET permission, the com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId Meta Data)

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

define activity in your mainfest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_facebook_login" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't know how I missed that but of code.

Comment: I also missed that somehow. In which point are we exactly add this?

Comment: @Kapil why this we have to write?

Comment: @PratikButani As per the docs "This Activity is a necessary part of the overall Facebook login process but is not meant to be used directly. Add this activity to your AndroidManifest.xml to ensure proper handling of Facebook login"

Comment: @KapilVats What is the value of the title_facebook_login string resource?

Answer (score 1):

One complet manifest with login in facebook:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eltondcr.youvox"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!--
    <receiver android:name="com.example.ServiceAutoStarter" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.eltondcr.youvox.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".GravacaoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FBActivity" />

    <activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="title_facebook_login" >
</activity>
</application>

<!-- <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" /> -->
```

Comment: is this still needed even if the facebook app is there on the mobile or only when it is not there